# Speed up Chromedriver/Selenium in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver

Hi i've developed a bot that automates the shopping process on a specific website. When testing it on my mac it works perfectly and can place an order quite fast. I have tried to run the script on an AWS EC2 instance using the free t2.micro tier with an Ubuntu instance.

The script runs fine and all the packages work but i've noticed the time it takes to open chrome in headless mode and finish the process is 5/6 times longer than when I run it on my local macbook. Ive tried all the suggested things in the chromedriver options to do with the proxy server but my EC2 instance still isn't fast enough.

Is it the small t2.micro free tier thats slowing me down or should i be using a different instance other than Ubuntu if I want to speed up my selenium script?

Answer (score 1):

You're using an incredibly small machine, which is going to be much slower than the powerful machine you're running locally.

Comment: So if I stay on ubuntu and just upgrade to t.2 medium I should see an increase in speed due to an upgrade by 1Gb memory? Or would it need to be a more significant upgrade in machine to get it running fast

Comment: You should use t3 instead of t2 instances, and you can keep stepping up the instance size until you reach a speed/price ratio you're happy with. If you are okay with having it go slow to save money there's nothing wrong with that- and if you want it to go faster then bigger machines will help (up to a point, of course).